# Strange inconsistency, database connection from require_once not working in only one place

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've encapsulated my MySQLi connection logic in a script named `connect_mysqli.php`.  This working just fine all over my project (9 other pages are having no trouble), but one page is returning this error:

```
Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\projectName\php_calls\AddItem.php on line 193
```

Here's the code that's not working in `AddItem.php`:

```
$sql = <<<HEREDOC
    UPDATE listing_data
    SET ebay_id = '$responseObj->ItemID'
    WHERE listing_id = '$database_listing_id'
HEREDOC;
require_once(__DIR__ . '/connect_mysqli.php'); //this creates $conn
$conn->query($sql); //this is line 193
```

And this is the code from `connect_mysqli.php`:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$db = "db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
```

Again, this is working without trouble in every other spot in the project.  Here's what I've tried so far:

I checked my SQL syntax.  I echoed the SQL query I'm attempting and tested it on the command line, the query is working fine.

Double check my SQL again.  I copied the code from a working database call into the `AddItem.php`.  It produces the same error.  I tested the original page where this code exists, it works correctly in that spot.

I checked to make sure require_once is working correctly.  To make sure my relative path was working correctly, and I am in the cwd that I expected I was in:

```
echo require_once(__DIR__ . '/connect_mysqli.php');
```

and it produced:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\projectName\php_calls/connect_mysqli.php
```

This was expected.  I opened Windows Power Shell and ran:

```
cat C:\xampp\htdocs\projectName\php_calls/connect_mysqli.php
```

This displays the code inside `connect_mysqli.php`!  I was beginning to guess my require_once was flawed.

Check to see if there's a naming collision.

```
var_dump(get_defined_vars());
```

There is only one `$conn`.

The connection is not being closed with `$conn->close();`.  If it's closing without my instruction I don't know how or why.

I copied and pasted the code from `connect_mysqli.php` into `AddItem.php` and the **error goes away.**  So somehow my `require_once` must be messing up my connection.  `AddItem.php` and `connect_mysqli.php` are in the same folder.  I tried connecting with this line instead:

```
require_once('connect_mysqli.php');
```

I still get an error.

Sorry for the incredibly lengthy question, I wanted to do my research and try everything before creating another question on the topic.  For now I can copy the database connection code into `AddItem` as a workaround, but it's bad practice, and there's clearly some important principle escaping me here that I'd like to understand.

**Edit:** more information

Nico Haase asked the question that put me on the right track.  Line 1 of `AddItem.php` is a require_once:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '\return_item_php_obj_by_id.php');
```

and inside `return_item_php_obj_by_id.php` we have the culprit:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/connect_mysqli.php');
//edited out irrelevant code
mysqli_close($conn);
```

In the original post I said "There's no `$conn->close()` hiding anywhere."  Clearly I was mistaken.  I found the hidden close().  When I comment this out, the connection works.  Now I've accidentally made my code really hard to read, and I don't want to use a database connection that far away on the stack.  Should I leave the connection open so I can use it again with `AddItem.php`?  What's best practice in this case?

Comment: Is there probably a second line of `require_once(__DIR__ . '/connect_mysqli.php')` anywhere in your file? As the name states, this is only included once. And if such includes happen in different scopes, `$conn` might not be available

Comment: Second thought: is there any call of `$conn->close()`?